# Rails Form Field Duplicate Error Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I'm getting duplicate error messages around my form fields - one for the label and one for the field. I have no idea why the label is getting assigned the error message. I've included all the related code that I know of. Please help if you can, thanks! 
rails version **3.0.11**

generated html:

```
<div class="field">
<div class="field_with_errors"><label for="customer_email">Email</label><br /><span class="validation-error">&nbsp;
      has already been taken</span></div><br />
<div class="field_with_errors"><input id="customer_email" name="customer[email]" size="30" type="text" value="asdrummo@gmail.com" /><br /><span class="validation-error">&nbsp;
      has already been taken</span></div>
</div>
```

Password

in my application.rb:

```
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  if instance.error_message.kind_of?(Array)
    %(<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}<br /><span class="validation-error">&nbsp;
      #{instance.error_message.join(',')}</span></div>).html_safe
  else
    %(<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}<br /><span class="validation-error">&nbsp;
      #{instance.error_message}</span></div>).html_safe
  end
end
```

my form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@customer, :url => {:action => 'save_customer'}) do |f| %>

<% if @customer.errors.any? %>
<%= error_messages_for(@customer)%>
<% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

the error_messages_for(object):

```
def error_messages_for( object )
    render(:partial => 'shared/error_messages', :locals => {:object => object})
end
```

shared/error_messages:

```
<div class="error">Please correct the <%= pluralize(@customer.errors.count, "error") %> below and resubmit.</div>
```

and lastly, my validations:

```
validates :email, :presence => true, :length => {:maximum => 100 }, :format => EMAIL_REGEX, :confirmation => true, :uniqueness => true
validates :password, :on => :update_password, :presence => true, :confirmation => true, :length => { :minimum => 5}
```

**UPDATE**:

with the code removed from application.rb, i still get the following (example for the email validation error):

```
<div class="field">
  <div class="field_with_errors"><label for="customer_email">Email</label></div><br />
  <div class="field_with_errors"><input id="customer_email" name="customer[email]" size="30" type="text" value="asdrummo@gmail.com" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you say that there is a message "for the label" and one "for the field" ?

Comment: The warnings are showing up starting with '<br /> so that they appear under the element with the error - as you can see from the HTML, the error is being displayed under the label and under the field. No idea why.

Comment: Note that **you are running an old version of Rails 3.0**, the latest patch version is 3.0.11 and contains **important security fixes** and thus you should update your Rails version.

Comment: thanks for that information - i've updated to rails 3.0.11. problem still persists. it might be possible that i changed some code this past summer to enable error classes to be assigned to the labels(?) i did have dynamic forms installed as a plug-in/gem but i've uninstalled and deleted. any ideas?

Comment: I found the interim answer to be adding a clause to not include the instance if the error was to be assigned to the label tag:

 if html_tag =~ /^<label/
        %(<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div>).html_safe
 ...
the label will still be assigned an error class which is good but no more duplicate text!

Comment: i'm having the same issue, did you find a proper solution?